# How to display data upon PHP API call in Ionic3

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am unable to display data in ionic3 upon an PHP API call. When i do console.log it shows the complete data but when I try to show it on my page, it doesn't display. 
Can any one help me to get out of this?

**feed.ts**

```
 posts: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public http: Http) {

    // this.questioncontent   =[
    //   {questionasked:"Question Asked. Computer Programming",question:"how can i learn Ionic Framework?",time:"22 min",follow:"1"},
    //   {questionasked:"Question Asked. human behaviour",question:"what is the real life example of deadlock",time:"justnow",follow:"101"}
    // ];
    this.http.get('https://schoolinformation.000webhostapp.com/phpapi.php').map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.posts = data.data
        console.log(this.posts);
   },
  err => {
      console.log("Oops!");
  }
);
```

**feed.html**

```
<div id="question" *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <div id="questionaksedby"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="Question"><b>{{post.data.question}}</b></div>
    <br>
    <div id="questiontime">
         Last asked:
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="answerbtn">
        <button class="btn-lg">Answer</button> Follow:
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Improved the syntax and formatting

Comment: any errors in log?

Comment: `https://schoolinformation.000webhostapp.com/phpapi.php` is giving only object there is not `data.data` available in it when i tried in browser

Comment: so now how can i display my data any idea?

Comment: Please don't alter your question in a way that invalidates answers you've received. If you have a new question then ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your retrieved data is an *Object* and *not an array* so you cannot use the `*ngFor` loop.

In order to ensure it prints in view correctly when you receive the data, you can use safe navigation operator (`?`) in your html.

```
<div id="question">
    <div id="questionaksedby"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="Question"><b>{{posts?.questionasked}}</b></div>
    <br>
    <div id="questiontime">
         Last asked:
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="answerbtn">
        <button class="btn-lg">Answer</button> Follow:
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting the data correctly? see the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052281/how-to-display-data-upon-php-api-call-in-ionic3/46053455?noredirect=1#comment79066180_46052281

Comment: i get an error like  this  "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: if i write console.log(this.posts) then it will display data like this Object
=>"follow
:
10
question
:
"Alfred Hitchcock"
questionasked
:
"Rear Window"
time
:
"jut now"
__proto__
:
Object  "

Comment: you should edit the original question with your json information

Comment: Thank You so Much Its Works For Me @suraj

Comment: glad it worked.. consider accepting the answer and closing the issue

Comment: i have another problem in this @suraj i am aditing my question

Comment: If you have a different problem I suggest creating a new question.. not change the existing one.. I was telling you to add additional info  to existing question

Comment: i have same problem but now i fatch data from database and i cant show the data i cant understand what type of data it is ither it is "object" or "array"

Comment: since this is solved.. that may be an issue elsewhere.. Form another question with an MCVE